# Returning JSON from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm writing a simple App Engine app.

I have a simple page that allows a user to move a marker on a Google map instance. Each time the user drops the marker, I want to return the long/lat to my Python app.

```
function initialize() {

  ... // Init map

  var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
    // I want to return the marker.x/y to my app when this function is called ..
  });

}
```

To my (admittedly limited) knowledge, I should be:

1). Returning a JSON structure with my required data in the listener callback above

2). In my webapp.RequestHandler Handler class, trying to retrieve the JSON structure during the *post* method.

I would very much like to pass this JSOn data back to the app without causing a page reload (which is what has happened when I've used various post/form.submit methods so far).

Can anyone provide me with some psuedo code or an example on how I might achieve what I'm after?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the page to update, then you need to use a XMLHttpRequest.  In this example, i'm using the client-side `function Request(function_name, opt_argv)` and server-side `RPCHandler` from this [Google App Engine example](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html).  I haven't tested this, but it would look like:

Client-side Javascript

```
function initialize() {

  ... // Init map

  var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(position) {
    Request('update_marker_position', [ unique_identifier, position.lat(), position.lng() ] );
  });

}
```

Server-side Python

```
# Create database model for LatLng position
class LatLng(db.Model):
    lat = db.IntegerProperty()
    lng = db.IntegerProperty()

...

class RPCMethods:
    """ Defines the methods that can be RPCed.
    NOTE: Do not allow remote callers access to private/protected "_*" methods.
    """

    def update_marker_position(self, *args):
        # args[0] - unique identifier, say GAE db key
        # args[1] - lat
        # args[2] - lng
        # Note: need to do some checking that lat and lng are valid
        
        # Retrieve key and update position
        position = LatLng.get(db.Key(args[0])
        if position:
            position.lat = args[1]
            position.lng = args[2]
        else:
            position = LatLng(
                lat= args[1], 
                lng= args[2]
            )
        position.put()
        
        payload = {
            'lat': args[1],
            'lng': args[2],
        }
        return payload
```

You'll need to create the db entry when you serve up the page, and store the db key client side.  You could also use some other unique identifier.  In this case, I assumed you stored it as a global variable 'unique_identifier'.

As well, you'll need to add a callback function to handle the returning payload (with members 'lat' and 'lng').  From the example, I believe you just add your callback function as the zeroth parameter in the opt_argv array of Request.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

The way to prevent a page reload is to handle this with AJAX on the web page side.

Using jquery, you might do something like this:

```
$("#testform").submit(function() {
    // post the form values via AJAX...
    var postdata = {lat: $("#lat").val(), long: $("#long").val()} ;
    $.post('/submit', postdata, function(data) {
        // and set the location with the result
        $("#location").html(data['location']) ;
       });
    return false ;
    });
```

Assuming you have a web page something like this:

```
<p>Enter lat and long:</p>
<form id="testform" action="#" method="post">
    <p>
    <label for="lat">Lat:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lat" /> <br />
    <label for="long">Long:</label>
    <input type="text" id="long" /> <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Get Location" />
    </p>
</form>

<p>The location is:</p><p id="location">(enter lat and long above)</p>
```

and then have the python code return the location in a JSON dict.

Finally, I would recommend having a graceful fallback: if the user has JavaScript disabled, do a regular post to e.g. `/getlocation` and reload, and then have JavaScript override this to submit to a special URL that returns json, like `/getlocationajax`